# SQL Server SQLPackage Drift Report doesn't work on SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, sqlpackage

I'm trying to run a Drift Report from SQL Server 2017 (RTM).  Running into the following issue...

```
> sqlpackage /a:DriftReport /tcs:"Data Source=DAYPOCSQLAS01;Trusted_Connection=true;Database=ChuckD" /op:drift.txt
```

> Generating drift report for database 'ChuckD' on server 'DAYPOCSQLAS01'.
> Databases registered as a DAC database must be hosted by an instance of SQL 2005 SP4, SQL 2008 SP2, SQL 2008 R2, SQL 2012, SQL 2014 or Microsoft Azure SQL Database.
> Unable to proceed with DAC operations on the target instance because it does not support DACs. Specify another instance, or upgrade to a version that supports DACs.

I know you're probably thinking "well yeah, you have to run it on one of the listed SQL Server versions in the error message".  My thought is that it should definitely run on SQL Server 2017.  Any insight on this?

Comment: What version of sqlpackage are you running? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: 18.5.1 and bunch of other versions I found lingering on my hard drive.

Comment: Any help @DavidBrowne-Microsoft?

Comment: Can you try the following:   - Check the @@version for the instance

- Attempt to reinstall the sqlpackage.exe utility.

- After reinstall ensure you are executing the sqlpackage.exe tool from the current path. Example:

 

PS C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin> ./sqlpackage /a:DriftReport /tcs:"Data Source=.;Trusted_Connection=true;Database=AdventureWorks2012" /op:'c:\temp\f'

 

- Re-register the database as a datatier application from SSMS.